# What exactly is Metadata in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

What exactly is MetaData SQLAlchemy? I have a hard time understanding this.

And what is the difference between MetaData and Engine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Metadata is a collection of table definitions. Engine is the dialect and connection details of a specific database, along with a connection pool that holds any connections already established with that database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't realize Metadata was a collection of table definitions. But I had intuition that Engine was just that.